# How to stop page content from flowing into SideNav Semantic-ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

I am trying to make a page with a side navigation bar. I am using semantic-ui, kinda new to it and using its grid. The thing is that the rest of the page content flows under the `sidenav` and gets hidden beneath it, I don't know how to stop this behavior.

I tried putting the `sidenav` into a 4 width column and the rest of the page into a 12 width, I tried different parameters/classes for the `sidenav` but I cant get it to stop flowing into it. Here the vertical menu has the 'left fixed' option

I've tried without it fixed, trying adding a visible sidebar. From the docs, it doesn't seem like content should flow under it not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<html >
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.2/semantic.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/stylesheets/app.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="ui inverted teal menu">
      <div class="right menu">
        <a class="ui item">Sign In</a>
        <a class="ui item">Login</a>
        <a class="ui item">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui left fixed vertical menu teal inverted">
        <div class="header item"><a href='/'>MyApp</a></div>
        <%  for(var cat in allCats) { %>
            <div class="item">
                    <a class='header' href="/<%= cat %>" ><%= cat %></a>
                    <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <% for(var subCat in cat) { %>
                                <li><a class="item" href="cat/subCat" ><%= subCat %></a></li>
                        <% } %>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <a class="item">About Us</a>
    </div>

<h1 class='title-format'>Welcome to MyApp!!!</h1>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.2/semantic.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here the simple `h1` that says "welcome to my app" when I make the window smaller goes under my side navbar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making use of class `stackable`,`computer reversed` and `tablet reversed` i was able to get the expected result. please check the below working example.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.2/semantic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico">

<div class="ui inverted teal menu">
  <div class="right menu">
    <a class="ui item">Sign In</a>
    <a class="ui item">Login</a>
    <a class="ui item">Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui grid stackable computer reversed tablet reversed">
  <div class="thirteen wide column">
    <h1 class='title-format'>Welcome to MyApp!!!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="three wide column">
    <div class="ui left vertical menu teal inverted">
      <div class="header item">
        <a href='/'>MyApp</a>
      </div>
      <%  for(var cat in allCats) { %>
        <div class="item">
          <a class='header' href="/<%= cat %>">
            <%= cat %>
          </a>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <% for(var subCat in cat) { %>
                <li>
                  <a class="item" href="cat/subCat">
                    <%= subCat %>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% } %>
      <a class="item">About Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Girish, Thank You but this doesnt work for me, I had tried this already but it still goes under the side navbar for some reason, when made small.

Comment: remove `position:fixed` in smaller screens

Comment: please check the above edited code snippet now it contains `stackable` class which will stack the columns in smaller screens, and have removed `fixed` from sidebar

Comment: Sorry this doesnt work well at all the page content just stacks under the sidenav

Comment: please check the above snippet now, hope this is what u are expecting.

Comment: Hi Girish, the content still flows under the sidenav...... I dont know why this is so hard to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Grid structure, see docs: https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#/overview

And in order to have fixed width of your columns, I`m afraid that you cannot do it (not sure) with semantic-ui default classes, I believe you have to use a custom CSS classes to define the fixed width.

The HTML:

```
<div class="ui grid">
   <div class="sixteen wide column"> ... </div>
   <div class="custom-sidebar wide column"> ... </div>
   <div class="custom-content wide column"> ... </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui.grid > .column.custom-sidebar {
    width: 16em !important;
}
.ui.grid > .column.custom-content {
    width: calc(100% - 16em) !important;
}
```

```css
.ui.grid > .column.custom-sidebar {
    width: 16em !important;
}
.ui.grid > .column.custom-content {
    width: calc(100% - 16em) !important;
}
```

```html
<html >
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.2/semantic.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/stylesheets/app.css">
        <link rel="icon"       type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="sixteen wide column">
      <div class="ui inverted teal menu">
        <div class="right menu">
          <a class="ui item">Sign In</a>
          <a class="ui item">Login</a>
          <a class="ui item">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-sidebar wide column">   
    <div class="ui left fixed vertical menu teal inverted">
        <div class="header item"><a href='/'>MyApp</a></div>
            <div class="item">
                    <a class='header' href="" >cat</a>
                    <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                                <li><a class="item" href="cat/subCat" >subcat</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <a class="item">About Us</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-content wide column">
    <h1 class='title-format'>Welcome to MyApp!!!</h1>
    
    </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.2/semantic.min.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Girish, I had done it with a grid before but it didn't work, however with the 25% and putting the grid before the top van as well seems to make it work, however the 25% makes the side bar very ugly its too big when the page is maxed and too small when it is minimized, is there another way???

Comment: make it `max-width: 25% !important;` instead then.

Comment: is there a way I can make it exactly the size it is without the 25%??? should I try and use a pixel value or would that be unresponsive/bad??? or use a max and min width maybe???

Comment: you can use class `doubling`(A doubling grid will double column widths for each device jump.) -
https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#doubling

Comment: I tried adding a min-width to the sidenav but then the page content bleeds into it again. And if I leave only max-width then the sidenav becomes really small. I just want it to stay a fixed size and only for the page content to shrink

Comment: Actually it doesn't bleed in with the h1 but with more content, I have a page with a grid in it it does bleed in even with the max-width 25% set

Comment: even with just he h1 it flows a bit under the sidenav at certain levels, still can't get this to work

Comment: Hey Mate, I believe you will have to use custom CSS to have it with fixed width, please see my updated answer. Basically I defined two CSS classes `.custom-sidebar` and `.custom-content` with defined width. let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out it was very simple, no need to use the grid system at all, Just some css modification:

```
#sidenav {
    min-width: 200px;
}

#mainViewArea {
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

That did it!!!

Thanks for those who helped, it drove me in the right direction, hope this helps someone.